# Insert only selected field with multiple value into one value with delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, one is to record the queue, another one is record the data for each queue

Queue Table

| Id | Queue_Id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

Data Table

| Id | Queue_Id | Item | Field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | Vege |
| 2 | 1 | B | Fruit |
| 3 | 1 | A | Vege |
| 4 | 1 | B | Fruit |

Now I have to create a stored procedure that will return a temp table in below format

| Queue_Id | Item | Field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Vege, Fruit |
| 1 | B | Vege, Fruit |

If I `SELECT` using `String_AGG()`, the `Queue_Id` will be also returning like this Queue_Id = (1,1), but I just want it to display only Queue_Id = (1)

Comment: Did you get your A/B backward? With the sample data I'm not sure how you would ever expect Fruit to be returned for A, or Vege returned for B

Comment: Huh?  How does `Fruit` get associated with `item A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group by as follows:

```
Select d.queue_id, d.item,
       Max(Select String_agg(field,',') within group (order by field) 
          from (Select distinct field 
                  from data dd where dd.queue_id = d.queue_id) t) t ) as fields
  From data d
  Join queue q on d.queue_id = q.queue_id
 Where q.id = 1
 Group by queue_id, item
```